# onClick Rendering is not happening ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am creating a web application with react.js also using react-bootstrap.

What I want to accomplish is when user click on button then modal will appear but that is not happening.

Button code

```
<div className="rightButtons">
  <button name="updateItem" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => { this.onUpdateItem(this.props.selectedAppTypeId)}} >Update Item</button>
</div>
```

function which will be called.

```
onUpdateItem = (id) => {
    return (
      <div className="static-modal">
        <Modal.Dialog>
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>One fine body...</Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any help would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning HTML into your onClick handler, and not into the Component's render method. If you want to show HTML content after an onClick, you need to actually return those HTML elements within the actual render. Try this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
   state = { 
       showModal: false
   }

   renderModal = () => {
    return (
      <div className="static-modal">
        <Modal.Dialog>
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>One fine body...</Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Dialog>
      </div>
    );
   }

     render() {
      return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({showModal:true})}> Show </button>
            {this.state.showModal && this.renderModal()}
        </div>
     )
    }
}
```

Edit: You can also export that entire Modal return statement into its own component, and conditionally render the component when the showModal state is true.

```
const ModalComponent = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="static-modal">
          <Modal.Dialog>
            <Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>One fine body...</Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button>Close</Button>
              <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal.Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        showModal: false
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({showModal:true})}>
                    Show Modal
                </button>
                {this.state.showModal && <ModalComponent id='0af141random'/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that you're passing a react *function component* as an event handler; the return value of the function is a react component, but calling the function by itself won't mount that component in the DOM and display it.

A better way to make this happen might be to place your Modal component in your component hiearchy, and control whether it is shown by using a callback to change the state of a parent component.

Something like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  showModal() {
    this.setState{
      modalActive: true;
    }
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Button onClick={showModal}>Show me the modal!</Button>
      <Modal active={this.state.modalActive} />
    </div>
  }
}

const modalComponent = (props) => {
  return (<div style={{ display: (props.isActive) ? "block" : "none "}}>
    <h1>I'm a modal!</h1>
  </div>)
}
```

I haven't checked, but I'm sure React Bootstrap has its own prop for displaying/hiding modals.

**EDIT**: Here's a code example from the react bootstrap documentation that shows it in use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live